# running powershell scripts as scheduled tasks

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, office365

I got a couple of scripts which perform mailboxes moves to the cloud on office 365. The scripts sometimes fails and others not, I don't have any clue on why it 
fails but I guess it is because the service is not available when the task is executed, anyways, the point is that these scripts are running as scheduled tasks and one must be 
executed before of other, how I could detect if the first tasks failed and if so then reschedule the second task.

The tasks are running powershell v2 cmdlets on windows 2008 r2 so I'm using Task Scheduler.

I wonder if I should save some entries into a text file, to use a different task scheduler or maybe run each job using powershell, in the following way:

```
foreach ($script in $scripts)
{
    #check status in a text file
    $job = start-job -Filepath c:\myscript.ps1 -AsJob
    Wait-Job $job -Timeout 180
}
```

What would be the best approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to query / enable or reschedule your tasks. Or you can use the [COM object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the scheduler (beware schtasks output is language dependant). With one or other method check the lastTaskResult and reschedule or not your other task.

Examples:

Get all tasks of the root folder using COM object

```
icm -AsJob -JobName getTasks -ComputerName $computername  -ScriptBlock{
    $Schedule = new-object -com("Schedule.Service")
    $Schedule.connect($env:computername)
    $Tasks = $Schedule.getfolder("\").gettasks(0)
    $Tasks | Select-Object  Name,Path,State,Enabled,LastRunTime,LastTaskResult 
    }
```

Get a particular task with schtasks

```
schtasks /query /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Autochk\Proxy" /v /fo csv  |ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: thanks Kayasax, you think that upgrade to PS3 and use PSScheduledJob module would be a valid option. it does make sense?

Comment: doesnt cost too much effort to upgrade... :) i cannot answer as i not used that module, could make sense if you only run powershell scripts as tasks ?